# Available IPs list

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have list of IPs and their respective hostname allocations like this:

```
192.168.1.1 - GW          
192.168.1.2 - HOSTA 
192.168.1.3 - HOSTB        
192.168.1.7 - HOSTC
```

The list is big. More than 4000 rows with different subnets.

I want to extract via BASH the available IPs which are the ones that in the above list.

For instance, IPs:

```
192.168.1.4 
192.168.1.5 
192.168.1.6
```

To accomplish I'm trying to compare the IP numbers of the last octect with a {1-255} list.
If the numbers of the last octect is not in list then the IP is available.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are the leading line enumerations actually in your file?

Comment: No, that was only for the sake of listing, but the list is not enumrated. only the IPs and hostnames.

Comment: It's very important to represent your file exactly with question like this to save a lot of wasted effort. If `awk` is an acceptable solution then see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` you could do:

```
$ awk 'function f(){while(++a!=$4&&a<257)print IP,a}
       a+1!=$4&&NR>1{f()}{a=$4;IP=$1OFS$2OFS$3}END{f()}' FS='[. ]' OFS=. file
```

This will print

```
192.168.1.4 
192.168.1.5 
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.9
192.168.1.10
...
192.168.1.254
192.168.1.255
192.168.1.256
```

If you want to to treat the last IP `192.168.1.7` as the upper limit and not print the available IPs above just remove the `END` block `END{f()}`.

Comment: Very nice,though we could deploy a threshold octect output up to 255. It's getting values over that. But I got the main Idea. Thanks for sharing.